Questions regarding math in the Approximately Optimal Approximate Reinforcement Learning paper by Kakade
I have some problems understanding some aspects of the paper "Approximately Optimal Approximate Reinforcement Learning" by Kakade and the TRPO paper by Schulman. There is a part that argues
\begin{align} L_\pi(\tilde{\pi}) = \eta(\pi) + \sum_s \rho_\pi(s) \sum_a \tilde{\pi}(a|s)A_\pi(s,a). \tag{3} \end{align}
Note that $L_\pi$ uses the visitation frequency $\rho_\pi$ rather than $\rho_{\tilde{\pi}}$, ignoring changes in state visitation density due to changes in the policy. However, if we have a parameterized policy $\pi_\theta$, where $\pi_\theta(a|s)$ is a differentiable function of the parameter vector $\theta$, then $L_\pi$ matches $\eta$ to first order (see Kakade & Langford (2002)). That is, for any parameter value $\theta_0$,
\begin{align} L_{\pi_{\theta_0}}(\pi_{\theta_0}) =& \eta(\pi_{\theta_0}), \\ \nabla_\theta L_{\pi_{\theta_0}}(\pi_\theta)|_{\theta=\theta_0} &= \nabla_\theta \eta(\pi_\theta)|_{\theta=\theta_0}. \tag{4} \end{align}
Equation (4) implies that a sufficiently small step $\pi_{\theta_0} \to \tilde{\pi}$ that improves $L_{\pi_{\theta_0}}$ will also improve $\eta$, but does not give us any guidance on how big of a step to take.
Checking the Kakade paper as this is the reference, I found the following part that the TRPO paper probably refers to.
A more reasonable situation is one in which we are able to improve the policy with some $\alpha > 0$ using a $\pi'$ that chooses better actions at most but not all states. Let us define the policy advantage $A_{\pi,\mu}(\pi')$ of some policy $\pi'$ with respect to a policy $\pi$ and a distribution $\mu$ to be
\begin{align} A_{\pi,\mu}(\pi') \equiv E_{s\sim d_{\pi,\mu}} [E_{a\sim\pi'(a|s)} [A_\pi(s,a)]] . \end{align}
The policy advantage measures the degree to which $\pi'$ is choosing actions with large advantages, with respect to the set of states visited under $\pi$ starting from a state $s \sim \mu$. Note that a policy found by one step of policy improvement maximizes the policy advantage.
It is straightforward to show that $\frac{\partial \eta_\mu}{\partial \alpha}|_{\alpha=0} = \frac{1}{1-\gamma}A_{\pi,\mu}$ (using equation
3.2), so the change in $\eta_\mu$ is:
\begin{align} \Delta \eta_\mu = \frac{\alpha}{1-\gamma}A_{\pi,\mu}(\pi') + O(\alpha^2). \tag{4.2} \end{align}
Hence, for sufficiently small $\alpha$, policy improvement occurs if the policy advantage is positive, and at the other extreme of $\alpha = 1$, significant degradation could occur. We now connect these two regimes to determine how much policy improvement is possible.
Somehow I cannot derive this approximation and don't see how the math works here (taking the differential there for example and also $\alpha$ doesn't appear in the part of the TRPO paper). Could anyone enlighten me?
